# Check if at least one checkbox is checked in PHP

Tags: php, validation, checkbox

I already found a question called "Check if at least 1 checkbox is ticked in PHP", but that did not meet my needs because I am an organized person and that didn't seem like an organized way of doing it.  I have this checkbox code:

```
    <h1>_________</h1>
   <p>Which records would you like to see?<br />
   Enter as little or as many criteria as you want and then press Submit.</p>
   <form method = "get" action = "http://www.its-a-secret.com/validation.php">
     <div>
       <span>
         <label for = "lastname" id = "txtlabel">Last Name</label>
         <input type = "text" name = "lastname" />
       </span>
       <span>
         <label for = "firstname" id = "txtlabel">First Name</label>
         <input type = "text" name = "firstname" />
       </span>
       <span>
         <label for = "company" id = "txtlabel">Company</label>
         <?php
           session_start();
           mysql_connect("______","_______","________");
           mysql_select_db("____");
           $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT company FROM _____";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           print "<select name = 'company' id = 'company'> \n";
           print "           <option></option> \n";
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             print "           <option value='" . $row['company'] . "'>" . $row['company'] . "</option> \n";
           }
           print "         </select> \n";
         ?>
       </span>
       <span id = "spanaccttype">
         <label for = "accttype" id = "txtlabel">Account type</label>
         <?php
           mysql_connect("_____","_____","_______");
           mysql_select_db("_____");
           $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT accttype FROM _____";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           print "<select name = 'accttype' id = 'accttype'> \n";
           print "           <option></option> \n";
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             print "           <option value='" . $row['accttype'] . "'>" . $row['accttype'] . "</option> \n";
           }
           print "         </select> \n";
         ?>
       </span>
       <span id = "spanproductname">
         <label for = "productname" id = "txtlabel">Product Name</label>
         <?php
           mysql_connect("______","______","______");
           mysql_select_db("_____");
           $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT productname FROM ______";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           print "<select name = 'productname' id = 'productname'> \n";
           print "           <option></option> \n";
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             print "           <option value='" . $row['productname'] . "'>" . $row['productname'] . "</option> \n";
           }
           print "         </select> \n";
         ?>
       </span>
       <span id = "spansharetype">
         <label for = "sharetype" id = "txtlabel">Share Type</label>
         <?php
           mysql_connect("_____","_____","______");
           mysql_select_db("_____");
           $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sharetype FROM _____";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           print "<select name = 'sharetype' id = 'sharetype'> \n";
           print "           <option></option> \n";
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             print "           <option value='" . $row['sharetype'] . "'>" . $row['sharetype'] . "</option> \n";
           }
           print "         </select> \n";
         ?>
       </span>
       <span id = "spanclosed">
         <label for = "closed" id = "txtlabel">Closed?</label>
         <?php
           mysql_connect("_________","______","__");
           mysql_select_db("____");
           $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT closed FROM _____";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           print "<select name = 'closed' id = 'closed'> \n";
           print "           <option></option> \n";
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             print "           <option value='" . $row['closed'] . "'>" . $row['closed'] . "</option> \n";
           }
           print "         </select> \n";
         ?>
       </span>
       <span id = "spanvaluegreaterthan">
         <label for = "valuegreaterthan" id = "txtlabel">Value Greater Than $</label>
         <input type = "number" name = "valuegreaterthan" />
       </span>
       <br />
    <span id = "spanwhatcolumnstoshowquestion">What columns would you like to show? (Note if none are checked none of the below will be shown.)</span>
           <table id = "showwhichcolumns">
             <tr>
               <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncompany" name = "showcolumncompany" value = "showcolumncompany" title = "Show column company" /><label for = "showcolumncompany" id = "check">Company</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnaccountnumber" name = "showcolumnaccountnumber" value = "showcolumnaccountnumber" title = "Show column account number" /><label for = "showcolumnaccountnumber" id = "check">Account #</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncontractdate" name = "showcolumncontractdate" value = "showcolumncontractdate" title = "Show column contract date" /><label for = "showcolumncontractdate" id = "check">Contract Date</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnclosed" name = "showcolumnclosed" value = "showcolumnclosed" title = "Show column close" /><label for = "showcolumnclosed" id = "check">Closed?</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumndateclosed" name = "showcolumndateclosed" value = "showcolumndateclosed" /><label for = "showcolumndateclosed" id = "check">Date Closed</label></td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumndob" name = "showcolumndob" value = "showcolumndob" /><label for = "showcolumndob" id = "check">DOB</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnproductname" name = "showcolumnproductname" value = "showcolumnproductname" /><label for = "showcolumnproductname" id = "check">Product Name</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncommissionpercent" name = "showcolumncommissionpercent" value = "showcolumncommissionpercent" /><label for = "showcolumncommissionpercent" id = "check">Commission %</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" name = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" value = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" /><label for = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" id = "check">Commission Payout (%)</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" name = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" value = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" /><label for = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" id = "check">Commission Payout ($)</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumntrailcomm" name = "showcolumntrailcomm" value = "showcolumntrailcomm" /><label for = "showcolumntrailcomm" id = "check">Trail Comm?</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" name = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" value = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" /><label for = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" id = "check">Guarantee %</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnaccounttype" name = "showcolumnaccounttype" value = "showcolumnaccounttype" title = "Show column account type" /><label for = "showcolumnaccounttype" id = "check">Account Type</label></td>
           </table>

           <p>
             <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "gobutton" />
           </p>
```

The form submits to a page called validation.php and this is the code for that page (I hardly have anything yet):

```
    <?php
      $lastname = $_REQUEST["lastname"];

      $firstname = $_REQUEST["firstname"];

      $company = $_REQUEST["company"];

      $accttype = $_REQUEST["accttype"];

      $productname = $_REQUEST["productname"];

      $sharetype = $_REQUEST["sharetype"];

      $closed = $_REQUEST["closed"];

      $valuegreaterthan = $_REQUEST["valuegreaterthan"];
      header("Location: http://www.its-a-secret/?lastname=" . htmlspecialchars($lastname) . "&firstname=" . htmlspecialchars($firstname) . "&company=" . htmlspecialchars($company));
    ?>
```

I would like to delete the HTML special characters, instead of changing them, I would also want the First Name and Last Name to only have one capital letter by just telling the user, and if they don't I want the SQL to be able to validate with the First Name or Last Name being all capital or something crazy like that.  I also want the First Name and Last Name to have all there space(s), if there are any.  I want there to be at least one checkbox checked.  I also want there to be a positive number that is a number in the number textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but here is my guess code:

```
  if(isset($_GET['showcolumnxx']) || isset($_GET['showcolumnxx']) || isset($_GET['showcolumnxx'] || etc.))  {
  $newUrl = "http://something.site.end/otherpageshere/[screenAfterValidation].php";
  header('Location: ' . $newUrl);
    } else {
       print "<p style = "color: red;">You must at least check one checkbox.</p>\n";

    }
```

Comment: This basically checks if any of the checkboxes is posted(Checked)

Comment: This basically checks if the user has submitted any data in the checkboxes which he had on HTML.

Comment: Where it says $newUrl = "http://something.site.end/otherpageshere/[screenAfterValidation].php"; It is actually possible to pass the validation and go directly to the screen after the validation, so it be better to just do the validation on the screen after the validation.

Answer (score 1):

This may help. I am just echoing in the same page. You can change it according to your need.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['check'])) {
    foreach($_GET['check'] as $check) {
        echo $check."<br />"; 
    }
}
?>

<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <span id = "spanwhatcolumnstoshowquestion">What columns would you like to show? (Note if none are checked none of the below will be shown.)</span>
       <table id = "showwhichcolumns">
         <tr>
           <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncompany" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumncompany" title = "Show column company" /><label for = "showcolumncompany" id = "check">Company</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnaccountnumber" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumnaccountnumber" title = "Show column account number" /><label for = "showcolumnaccountnumber" id = "check">Account #</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncontractdate" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumncontractdate" title = "Show column contract date" /><label for = "showcolumncontractdate" id = "check">Contract Date</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnclosed" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumnclosed" title = "Show column close" /><label for = "showcolumnclosed" id = "check">Closed?</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumndateclosed" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumndateclosed" /><label for = "showcolumndateclosed" id = "check">Date Closed</label></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumndob" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumndob" /><label for = "showcolumndob" id = "check">DOB</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnproductname" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumnproductname" /><label for = "showcolumnproductname" id = "check">Product Name</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncommissionpercent" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumncommissionpercent" /><label for = "showcolumncommissionpercent" id = "check">Commission %</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" /><label for = "showcolumncommissionpayoutpercent" id = "check">Commission Payout (%)</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" /><label for = "showcolumncommissionpayoutdollars" id = "check">Commission Payout ($)</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumntrailcomm" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumntrailcomm" /><label for = "showcolumntrailcomm" id = "check">Trail Comm?</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" /><label for = "showcolumnguaranteepercent" id = "check">Guarantee %</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" id = "showcolumnaccounttype" name = "check[]" value = "showcolumnaccounttype" title = "Show column account type" /><label for = "showcolumnaccounttype" id = "check">Account Type</label></td>
       </table>

       <p>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "gobutton" />
       </p>
</form>
```

Comment: @ewe, You did not ask for security. Any way, to get clean data, you have a lot of options such as, htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities(), stripcslashes or you can make your own custom function.